# Process through all the tables in postgresql stored procedures

Tags: postgresql

I need to loop through all the table in a database in postgresql.
is there a similar stored procedure like mssql sp_msforeachtable for postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use this query against [`information_schema.tables`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-tables.html):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type   = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND table_schema = 'public'
ORDER BY table_name
```

You might want to adjust the `table_schema` to suit your needs though. This query should (AFAIK) work in any database that follows the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the information schema: [information_schema.tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-tables.html).

Comment: How do I loop through all the tables then process the table, if I lookup in the information_schema.tables I still need to use a script to loop the returned results and execute / process each table. In ms sql you can just do something like this in the command line (sqlcmd) : sp_msforeachtable 'delete from ?'  that command will delete columns from all the tables in a database

Comment: @technomage, you need to learn how to use UNIX. `psql -At -c 'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables' | xargs -n 1 ....`